# Unable to bind JSON (returning from WCFRest) to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, wcf-rest

I have created a **WCFRestful** service which populates `JSON` data in following format

```
{"GetEmployeesJSONResult":"[{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000}]"}
```

I'm trying to display this data in HTML table using Knockout, but failed to do so far. However, hardcoded value gets displayed correctly.

*HTML and Knockout*

```
var HomeModel = function () {
        this.rows = ko.observableArray();
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {            

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:1249/Service1.svc/GetJsonAll',
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {                    
                //for (var x in data) {
                //    model.rows.push(data[x]);
                //}
                //model.rows(data);
                //console.log(model.rows);
                //var res = [{
                //    "Id": "1",
                //    "Name": "Mike",
                //    "Start_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
                //    "Finish_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
                //    "Salary": "Trainee"

                //}, {
                //    "Id": "2",
                //    "Name": "Jhon",
                //    "Start_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
                //    "Finish_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
                //    "Salary": "Trainee"
                //}, {
                //    "Id": "2",
                //    "Name": "Jhon",
                //    "Start_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
                //    "Finish_Date": "Sun 01/06/08",
                //    "Salary": "Trainee"
                //}];
                console.log(data);
                var model = new HomeModel();
                //ko.applyBindings(model);
                ko.applyBindings({
                    rows: data.GetEmployeesJSONResult
                });
            }
        });
    });


<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
            <tr>
                <!--<td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Salary"></td>-->
                <td>
                    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data))"></pre>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Could somebody please help me? I'm badly stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VlNM7qTPFz4NMWY3Iofr?p=preview)

```js
var data = {"GetEmployeesJSONResult":"[{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000},{\"Name\":\"Sumanth\",\"Id\":101,\"Salary\":5000}]"}

var HomeModel = function () {
        this.rows = ko.observableArray();
    };

  ko.applyBindings({
                    rows: JSON.parse(data.GetEmployeesJSONResult)
                });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" data-semver="3.1.1" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-debug.js"></script>
    
     <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <pre data-bind="text: Id"></pre>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <pre data-bind="text: Name"></pre>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <pre data-bind="text: Salary"></pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rony! JSON.parse(data.GetEmployeesJSONResult) did the trick. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, have you tried putting

```js
var HomeModel = function () {
        this.rows = ko.observableArray();
};
```

inside the `$(document).ready(function () {  };`?
Are you trying to get the values before they are in the DOM?

Comment: Yes. It is added.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this. JSON.parse(data.GetEmployeesJSONResult) did the trick.